# Django : retrieve data from models

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

I have a serious problem, I need to retrieve a query set from an unrelated model

my model:

```
# problem/models.py

User = get_user_model()

class Problem(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
    writer = models.ForeignKey(User,models.CASCADE)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=100) # my perfer is PositiveSmallIntegerField
    
class Submission(models.Model):
    submitted_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="submissions",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem,related_name="submissions",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
```

```
# contest/models.py

class Contest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    holder = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    finish_time = models.DateTimeField()
    is_monetary = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    price = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    problems = models.ManyToManyField(Problem)
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='authors')
    participants = models.ManyToManyField(User, related_name='participants')
```

**I trying to retrieve a query set of Submission like this** :

`<QuerySet [<Submission: Submission object (12)>, <Submission: Submission object (6)>, <Submission: Submission object (16)>, <Submission: Submission object (5)>, <Submission: Submission object (11)>, <Submission: Submission object (15)>, <Submission: Submission object (14)>, <Submission: Submission object (4)>, <Submission: Submission object (10)>, <Submission: Submission object (9)>, <Submission: Submission object (3)>, <Submission: Submission object (8)>, <Submission: Submission object (2)>, <Submission: Submission object (13)>, <Submission: Submission object (1)>, <Submission: Submission object (7)>]>`

**with the id of the Contest model** , but I don't know how it is possible

Comment: Have you tried something in the view or shell? I think you should have made ForeignKey which relates to Contest model.

Comment: You need a foreign key in Problem pointing to Contest.

Comment: @SunderamDubey I tried it in the shell but I can't figure out how to do it. and I cant create and modify the model  to add a new foreign key

Comment: @DamienBaldy in the Contest model I have a relation to Problem and User that those models have a relation with the Submission model its not possible to use this relation to retrieve data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your question correctly, what you're trying to do isn't possible in your current code. If you want to pull back all `Submission` objects filtered by a specific `Contest` id, you'll need to connect the two.

For instance, here's an example of what the call should be:

```py
submissions_by_contest = Submission.object.filter(contest.id=123) # or whatever the id/pk field is on Contest
```

However, in order for this to work, you'll have to modify the `Submission` model to something like this:

```py
from contest.models import Contest

class Submission(models.Model):
    submitted_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    participant = models.ForeignKey(User,related_name="submissions",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    problem = models.ForeignKey(Problem,related_name="submissions",on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    code = models.URLField(max_length=200)
    score = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    contest = models.ForeignKey(Contest,related_name="submissions")
```

This will connect the `Submission` model back to `Contest` as `contest`.

You may have to modify this a bit based on where your files are and what sub-directories are pythonic modules, but it should generally get you there.

EDIT: (based on context from reply)

Since you can't edit the initial code, you'll do something like this instead:

You have a connection that goes from Contest (m2m) to Problem and another that goes from Submission back to Problem. That's what you'll use.

First, you have the contest name or id or some identifier. You'll *get* that object.

```py
contest = Contest.objects.get(name="contest name") # or id
```

Then, you'll grab all of the Submissions that are *in* the `contest.problems`. Something like:

```py
submissions_by_contest = Submission.objects.filter(problem__in=contest.problems)
```

Syntax may differ slightly, but that's the connection you'd use.

Comment: actually, I think like you, but this question was asked me during an interview, and I can't change the default code. and I think there must be a trick to solve this problem but I can't figure it out, but almost like you say it's impossible

Comment: Oh! Ok, gotcha. Didn't realize you couldn't re-write the initial code.

I'm editing my response to reflect this.

Comment: thanks, it's had a little bug but its works, and I lost the interview but I learn new things thanks again Evan :))

Comment: Glad I could help! What was the bug?

Comment: thanks but I fixed it for myself, do you can update your answer like this?
 Submission.objects.filter(problem__in=contest.problems.all())

Comment: Oh yes, of course. You could always abstract that out too if it's more readable. Put the contest.problems.all() in a variable and then just pass that in. Depends on code standards and line length, etc.